# Liipimaginebundle Twig image Link Thumbnail - Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I have this link :

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/gallery/'~ i.imageName ~'' | imagine_filter('my_thumb')) }}" />
```

routing.yml

```
_liip_imagine:
resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

This config.yml for the bundle

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    my_thumb:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

But symfony keeps giving me this exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "path" for route "liip_imagine_filter" must match ".+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in VdvTimesheetsBundle:Timesheets:show_image.html.twig at line 16.
```

somebody got any idea whats wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try <img src="{{ asset( ('uploads/gallery/' ~ i.imageName) | imagine_filter('my_thumb')) }}" />

Comment: Check if the value of i`.imageName` is NOT NULL

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact problem, my team mates have the same setting and it works for them

Comment: Hi Stiven, I ended up using another bundle : https://github.com/Gregwar/ImageBundle

Comment: @Matteo thank you! Had an issue where a field I thought was required was not and caused some strange chaos.

Comment: Hi @RayFoss you are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

You can set a param with your link before and use it

```
{% set img = 'uploads/gallery/'~ i.imageName   %}
<img src="{{ img| imagine_filter('my_thumb')) }}" />
```